# Error: ng:areq Bad Argument when trying to define controllers in separate files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, angular-ui-router

My app worked great, but I had a huge app.js, so to modularize I put controllers into separate files and set up my app in a more conventional way. Now I'm getting the error above along with: 'Argument 'prodPageCtrl' is not a'. Here is my prodPageCtrl

```
"use strict";
angular.module("app.products").controller('prodPageCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
//grid def / config
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs : [
        {
            field: 'productId',
            name: 'View Product',
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><a data-ui-sref="app.products.readProductPage({productId: row.entity.productId})"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </a>'
        },
        {
            field: 'productId',
            name: 'Edit Product',
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><a data-ui-sref="app.products.editProductPage({productId: row.entity.productId})"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>' +
            '</div>',
        },
        {
            field: 'name'
        },
        {
            field: "upc"
        },
        {
            field: 'sku'
        },
        {
            field: 'mpn'
        },
        {
            field: 'productQty'
        },
        {
            field: 'unitOfMeasure'
        },
        {
            field: 'price'
        },
        {
            field: 'attribs'
        },
        {
            field: 'descript'
        }
    ]
};
//end grid options

$http.get("api/products")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.productArray = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);

        //parse JSON attributes string to objects TODO fix this by make attribute formatting better.
        for(var lcv = 0; lcv < $scope.productArray.length; lcv++) {
            $scope.productArray[lcv].attribs = JSON.parse($scope.productArray[lcv].attribs);
        }

        $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.productArray; //put data into ui-grid

    });

});`
```

here is my config in my app.js:

```
angular.module('app.products', ['ui.router']);
angular.module('app.products').config(function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('app.products', {
        abstract: true,
        data: {
            title: 'Products'
        }
    })
    .state('app.products.productPage', {
        url: '/products',
        data: {
            title: 'Products Page'
        },
        views: {
            "content@app": {
                templateUrl: 'products/views/products.html',
                controller: 'prodPageCtrl'
            }
        }

    })
    .state('app.products.addProductPage', {
        url: '/products/add',
        data: {
            title: 'Add a Product'
        },
        views: {
            "content@app": {
                templateUrl: 'app/app-views/views/AddProducts.html',
                controller: 'AddProdCntrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.products.readProductPage', {
        url: '/products/:productId',
        data: {
            title: 'View a Product'
        },
        views: {
            "content@app": {
                templateUrl: 'app/app-views/views/AddProducts.html',
                controller: 'readProdCntrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.products.editProductPage', {
        url: '/products/edit/:productId',
        data: {
            title: 'Edit a Product'
        },
        views: {
            "content@app": {
                templateUrl: 'app/app-views/views/AddProducts.html',
                controller: 'editProdCntrl'
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Finally is there a way to move the .config for my modules into other files, or even the whole module declaration? so as to further modularize. If you know where I can learn more about this please let me know! Thank you

Comment: RTFM, module declaration file first, then controller file, then configuration file. Order is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using GULP to conncat all of my js into a build folder